Shading on wrong face
Im new to 3d. Ive modelled a house and now trying to texture it, however the texture is showing on the wrong face for all the walls! So many hours I have put into this, I have no idea why the shading is wrong. The shading shows on the bottom face. Is there a way I can fix this? I created a new cube just to see whats going on and it happens to the cube too. Thanks.[![wrong face][1]][1]
EDIT: I added texture coordinates as suggested, but i now get wierd buckling on the shader. I tried adding a subdivision surface modifier so the shader would work better, but made no difference, so i deleted it. in fact it made the edges all distorted or made no difference on other objects. 
It may be due to unwrapping or my seams?

Or is it due to how i cut a hole using knife project which has resulted in endgons? Whatever they are :)

All of this is just a mess and confusing!!



Thank you Josh, you have been very helpful, this has fixed the mapping, hoever Im still getting pinching on the surface? Any idea what this would be?


By default textures are shading both sides of a planar face, but this is not what you're experiencing here.
Problem is that by default texures different from Image Textures (like your brick texture) use "Generated" Texture Coordinates, while you probably should use UV.
So, to solve add a Texture Coordinate node and plug its UV output to Vector input of the Brick texture.
If still in trouble check if your mesh is properly UV Unwrapped (but this will work on the default cube, which is always already unwrapped).

As the mesh is composed by big uneven N-gons, there will be uneven distorsions along borders of N-gons faces (this is what we call "Ugly topology").
To solve, you can select one face of a plane, press Shift G (Select similar > Coplanar), then go to the Select Menu > Select Loops > Select Boundary Loop, press Shift E (Edges Menu > Mark Seam), select again all surface, go to front ortographic view and press U > Unwrap > Project from view.
Repeat for the others surfaces.
When finished go to UV Edit window, select all, UV Menu > Pack Islands + Average Island scale, then rotate all 90 degrees if needed.


Thank you @joshsafanfelici I generated the texture cordinate which did the trick but now the shader looks nuts as you can see above where i edited my initial post.

I updated my answer.

Thank you Josh, as you can see above im still getting pinching. What could be doing this?
